Resizing TextFormField widget height
I'm trying to make TextFormField widget change its height depending on the window height at the moment.
I've wrapped TextFormField with ConstrainedBox, which changes height constraints to the desired value. In the TextFormField widget I change its height using contentPadding, in the verticalPadding of which i pass large values, which causes two problems.

If I were to use some finite number in vertical padding for contentPadding, larger than desired height, everything works and TextFormField visually changes its size, but if i use double.infinity (which seems more appropriate in this scenario), flutter throws following exception:

[ERROR:flutter/flow/layers/transform_layer.cc(23)] TransformLayer is constructed with an invalid matrix.

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURES LIBRARY ╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a pointer data packet:
'package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart': Failed assertion: line 1636 pos 18:
'transformed == position - offset': is not true.


Even if i use finite values as vertical padding for contentPadding, while the TextFormField looks visually fine, the cursor renders 1000 pixels above the TextFormField itself.


My TextFormField code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HeliosFormTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const HeliosFormTextField({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
    required this.labelText,
    required this.labelTextOnError,
    required this.validityCriteria,
    this.keyboardType,
    this.obscureText = false,
    this.clearOnError = true,
  });

  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String labelText;
  final String labelTextOnError;
  final bool Function(String?) validityCriteria;
  final bool obscureText;
  final bool clearOnError;
  final TextInputType? keyboardType;

  @override
  State<HeliosFormTextField> createState() => _HeliosFormTextFieldState();
}

class _HeliosFormTextFieldState extends State<HeliosFormTextField> {
  TextFieldStatus status = TextFieldStatus.none;
  ///Can change behaviour of the widget only if [widget.obscureText] is true
  bool obscureSymbols = true;



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.065,),
      child: TextFormField(
            cursorErrorColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            obscureText: widget.obscureText ? obscureSymbols : false,
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .bodyMedium
                ?.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
            autocorrect: false,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: status == TextFieldStatus.error ? widget.labelTextOnError : widget.labelText, 
              labelStyle: status == TextFieldStatus.error ? Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium?.copyWith(color: Colors.red) : Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium ,
              border: const OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)), borderSide: BorderSide.none),
              floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
              errorStyle: const TextStyle(
                height: 0,
                color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
              isDense: true,
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 1000), //If i were to put double.infinity instead 1000 the exception would trigger
              suffixIcon: widget.obscureText ? 
                 IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(obscureSymbols ? Icons.visibility_rounded : Icons.visibility_off_rounded),
                  onPressed: () => setState(() {
                    obscureSymbols = !obscureSymbols;
                  }),
              )
              : null,    
            ),
            controller: widget.controller,
            validator: (value) {
              if (!widget.validityCriteria(value)) {
                if (status != TextFieldStatus.error) {
                  setState(() {
                    status = TextFieldStatus.error;
                  });
                  if (widget.clearOnError) widget.controller.clear();
                }
                return '';
              }
              return null;
            },
            onChanged: (value) {
              if (status == TextFieldStatus.error &&
                  widget.validityCriteria(value)) {
                setState(() {
                  status = TextFieldStatus.none;
                });
              }
            },
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum TextFieldStatus {
  none,
  error,
  selected,
}


Really hoping for your help

Use the following properties to get the window width & height or device screen
double deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
double deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

Then Wrap the TextFormField with a SizedBox and set the values height and width accordantly
For example you can set height: deviceHeight/10

That doesn't work, the TextField itself saves its original size. Field should be the same height as the white button in the bottom
